# Is a global optimal solution of a convex problem always unique?

Tags: convex-optimization

I do not have a specific problem. Could a convex optimization problem (not strictly convex) have alternate solutions?

Comment: is the constant function convex ? hence the answer is no, we need the convex objective function being strictly convex around the minimum for the minimization problem having a unique solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Take for instance $$\inf_x \max\{|x|-1,0\}$$
The minimum value is clearly zero, but 
$$\mathop{\textrm{argmin}}_x \max\{|x|-1,0\}=[1,-1]$$
Notice that the set of optimal points is an interval. In the general, multivariate case, the set of optimal points for a convex optimization model *is always a convex set* (including possibly the empty set or a singleton).

Comment: You said Yes but then you said it is a convex set. So there could be many solutions?

Comment: The OP asked if a convex optimization problem can have multiple solutions. Hence I said yes...